# Date Argument format conversion from YYYYMMDD to DD-MON-YYYY

Tags: unix, aix

Can anyone let me know how to convert the date argument value YYYYMMDD(i.e. For ex- 20171010) to the date format 'DD-MON-YYYY'(i.e. 10-OCT-2017). 
Also i need to validate the date which user specifies as argument while executing the script.

**Note:** File System will only supports AIX commands. I have got suggestion like below which doesn't supported by AIX File system.

Refer the page - 
https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/173248-converting-date-yyyymmdd-dd-mon-yyyy.html

https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/58675-change-date-dd-mmm-yyyy-mm-dd-yyyy.html

date -f
date -j 
date -d

Comment: What date validation do you want?

Comment: I need to convert the date argument value from YYYYMMDD to 'DD-MON-YYYY' . also i need to validate whether the user gave the argument value correctly int the format 'YYYYMMDD'.

Comment: Without extra validation rules, you can't tell if the user entered YYYYMMDD or DDMMYYYY or MMDDYYYY (or other things).

Comment: can you let me know first how i can convert the date argument value format from YYYYMMDD to DD-MON-YYYY ?? then we will go for validation part

Comment: Um, which programming language are you using?

Comment: what is output of `uname -a ` and `lslpp -l | grep perl`

Comment: I am using Unix Shell scripting.

Comment: uname -a  -  AIX <servername>  , lslpp -l | grep perl - shows perl.libext & perl.rte in COMMITTED status

Comment: sh test.sh <arg1> 
For ex : sh test.sh 20161010
Final output should be : 10-OCT-2010
Inside the Shell script, the final output to be copied into an variable.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? The YYYYMMDD (or YYYY-MM-DD) format is standard and has a lot of advantages. In particular, it sorts correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
St_dt="$2"
St_D="${St_dt#??????}"
tmp="${St_dt%??}"
St_M="${tmp#????}"
if [ $St_M -le 0 -o $St_M -gt 12 ];
then
echo "$St_M is invalid month."
exit 1
fi
St_Y="${tmp%??}"
case "$St_M" in
01) St_M=JAN ;;
02) St_M=FEB ;;
03) St_M=MAR ;;
04) St_M=APR ;;
05) St_M=MAY ;;
06) St_M=JUN ;;
07) St_M=JUL ;;
08) St_M=AUG ;;
09) St_M=SEP ;;
10) St_M=OCT ;;
11) St_M=NOV ;;
12) St_M=DEC ;;
esac
Start_dt="${St_D}-${St_M}-${St_Y}"
echo "$Start_dt"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have Perl, a script like this should work:

```
#!/path/to/my/perl

use POSIX;
for (@ARGV ? @ARGV : <STDIN>) {
    my ($Y,$m,$d) = m/(\d\d\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)/;
    my $t = strftime "%d-%b-%Y", 0,0,0,$d,$m,$Y-1900;
    print "\U$t\n";
}
```

I don't know what features AIX `sh` provides but this might work:

```
#!/usr/bin/sh

case "$1" in
    [1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9])
        Y=${date%????}
        MD=${date#????}
        D=${MD#??}
        M=${MD%??}
        case "$M" in
            01) M=JAN ;;
            02) M=FEB ;;
            03) M=MAR ;;
            04) M=APR ;;
            05) M=MAY ;;
            06) M=JUN ;;
            07) M=JUL ;;
            08) M=AUG ;;
            09) M=SEP ;;
            10) M=OCT ;;
            11) M=NOV ;;
            12) M=DEC ;;
        esac
        echo "${D}-${M}-${Y}"
        ;;
    *)
        echo 1>&2 "invalid date"
        exit 1 ;;
esac
```

Comment: Got an error -   Syntax error at line 6 : `(' is not expected.

Comment: That's odd. Try amended version.

Comment: Can you let me know how to achieve the same in Unix shell scripting

Comment: How are you defining "Unix shell scripting"? Usually, the shell is just used to glue together commands (date, sed, awk, wc, sort, etc). Perl is just one of these commands. I've added a Bourne shell version but I don't know what features the AIX version supports.

Comment: Tried the above logic which you gave .. Only getting double '-' as output.

Comment: I don't have AIX. I suggest you insert `echo` debug statements at various points to find out what values the variables are taking. Apparently none of `Y`,`M` and `D` set being set correctly.

Comment: I have modified your query little bit and it worked for me. Thanks ;)

Comment: Great. Let me know what you changed so I can update the code for anyone who looks at this answer in future.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this [ksh93](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.osdevice/korn_shell_enhanced.htm) snippet as a start; it does two simple checks, then rearranges the inputted date as desired:

```
echo enter date
read d
if [ "${#d}" -ne 8 ]
then
  echo "bogus - not the right length"
else
  case $d in
    (*[^0123456789]*) echo "bogus - contains non-numerics"
        ;;
    (*) echo "the new date is: ${d:6:2}-${d:4:2}-${d:0:4}"
        ;;
  esac
fi
```

Comment: Do AIX shells support `${::}`? https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.osdevice/korn_shell_parmsub1.htm  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.osdevice/bourne_shell_cond_subs.htm

Comment: That's where I tested it; though I should clarify it's ksh93

Comment: Aha. I've never used AIX :) Ok. Found it: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.osdevice/korn_shell_enhanced.htm